# Brew installs not appearing in /usr/local/bin

Tags: installation, homebrew

I've installed a package using brew to a new Mac, `imagemagick`, and carried over a number of utilities that look for `convert`, a part of imagemagick in /usr/local/bin. These utilities can't find convert, using `which`, it's in `/opt/homebrew/bin/convert`.

In addition, I'm trying to get vscode to work from a command line. It's set up but running `code` gives the error `./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory`. Electron has been installed using brew but can only be found, again, in `/opt/homebrew/bin/convert`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `/opt/homebrew` is the default prefix on M1 macs, whilst `/usr/local/` is used with intel macs. How to transition seems unclear, although I recommend something like [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/417#discussioncomment-601662). Alternatively, you can always modify your PATH.

Comment: got it. many thanks.

Comment: Great, I'll write it up as an answer if that's ok.

Answer (score 27):

Since [Homebrew v3.0.0](https://brew.sh/2021/02/05/homebrew-3.0.0/), the default prefix is different depending on the chip architecture. The defaults are the following:

- `/opt/homebrew` on Apple silicon
- `/usr/local` on Intel

The main reason for this change was for [Rosetta 2 compatibility](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon).

It appears that you're trying to transition from an Intel machine to an Apple Silicon one. The simplest way to do this might be to reinstall all the formulae again via [brew bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/417#discussioncomment-601662). This shouldn't take very long thanks to the use of pre-built binaries.

Alternatively, you can always manually add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to your PATH (`/usr/local` is already in path).